# can not change default drawable icon

Tags: android, slidingmenu

im use this library for slidemenu https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu
can not change default drawable icon in SampleListFragment class
and give me error cannot be resolved or is not a field

```
public class SampleListFragment extends ListFragment {

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
        }

        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            SampleAdapter adapter = new SampleAdapter(getActivity());
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                adapter.add(new SampleItem("Sample List", android.R.drawable.ic_menu_call));
            }
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

        private class SampleItem {
            public String tag;
            public int iconRes;
            public SampleItem(String tag, int iconRes) {
                this.tag = tag; 
                this.iconRes = iconRes;
            }
        }

        public class SampleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SampleItem> {

            public SampleAdapter(Context context) {
                super(context, 0);
            }

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                }
                ImageView icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_icon);
                icon.setImageResource(getItem(position).iconRes);
                TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_title);
                title.setText(getItem(position).tag);

                return convertView;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is your log output? Which line error occurs? If you add them, it will be easy to answer.

Comment: cannot be resolved or is not a in line                 adapter.add(new SampleItem("Sample List", android.R.drawable.ic_menu_call));

Comment: delete "android." and make it "R.drawable.ic_menu_call" and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the search icon which is

```
adapter.add(new SampleItem("Sample List", android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search));
```

Note here

```
android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search
```

The default resource is from internal library so it is using the

```
android.R.drwable.resource_name
```

You need to change it to

```
R.drwable.resource_name
```

Finally you will have

```
adapter.add(new SampleItem("Sample List",  R.drawable.resource_name));
```

Comment: when change it give me erorr cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: May be the R.java file is not creating. Are you able to change the other icons? Or no one is changing?

Comment: Clean your project and rebuild, Perhaps R.java is not being recreated.